# Run PowerShell script within a maintenance plan

Tags: windows-server-2008, sql-server-2008, powershell

I have an [SQL Server 2008](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_SQL_Server#SQL_Server_2008) database, run on a 64-bit [Windows Server 2008](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Server_2008). I created a pretty simple PowerShell script that automates a bunch of tasks. I would like this script to run as part of our maintenance plan. How do I schedule it to run?

It needs to run as administrator - I know this is not ideal, but I am hoping I can have it execute as administrator. I currently open PowerShell as administrator and execute the script manually every morning.

In case it matters, the script:

- Zips the backup file ([7-Zip](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/7-Zip)) and moves it to our backup location
- Juggles some files - keeping the latest backup in a particular network location, and moving what was the most recent backup into the number two spot
- Deletes the .bak files

I want the script to run without counting on me to run it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can run your PowerShell script within SQL Server 2008 Agent (SQL Server's job scheduler). Using SQL Server Management Studio, create a SQL Server job and select a PowerShell job step. In the job step information specify the full path to your PowerShell script file.

Answer (score 1):

Try this: http://www.searchmarked.com/windows/how-to-schedule-a-windows-powershell-script.php

In short, save the PowerShell script as a .ps1 file, make sure PowerShell will execute PowerShell scripts, create a bat file that calls powershell and feeds it your script and then schedule the .bat file.

And here's a juicy Google search for good measure: http://www.google.com/search?q=schedule+powershell+script

Comment: thanks.  I was under the impression that SQL2008 and Powershell shared some functionality, and that I might be able to do this based on the SQL schedule rather than just timing it with windows.  
This would work too - thanks for the pointers!

Comment: You may well be able to use SQL scheduler, but I'm unfamiliar with it. "Whatever works" =)

Comment: Indeed - I have set it up like this and put in a buffer of time that I expect the SQL maintenance plan will take to run.  Gets the job done for now.  If anyone else knows a way to run this within SQL Server please share